# stackdriver ip range to allow in kubernetes network policy on gke

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, stackdriver, kubernetes-networkpolicy

We are running some node.js code on gke and are directly logging to stackdriver using googles @google-cloud/logging-winston library - the logging is working, thats not an issue.
We are also using kubernetes network-policies to limit traffic to/from our pods.

I cant figure out which ip ranges to allow in the egress policy to get the stackdriver logging working. 
When I allow all destinations, the logging is working but I would like to narrow down that a bit...

Comment: I would suggest allowing all destinations. The reason why is that even though you can pull the ranges for "googleapis.com", the ranges can change. Also, GCP does not share the IP ranges for each API publically.

Answer (score 0):

The IPs where stackdriver logging API requests are sent can be found using this command:

```
dig @8.8.8.8 googleapis.com
```

You should get these following IPs as a result:

```
googleapis.com.         299     IN      A       74.125.141.147
googleapis.com.         299     IN      A       74.125.141.104
googleapis.com.         299     IN      A       74.125.141.103
googleapis.com.         299     IN      A       74.125.141.99
googleapis.com.         299     IN      A       74.125.141.106
googleapis.com.         299     IN      A       74.125.141.105
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if using dns answers is a valid approach, as the current dns result is only a part of the truth.
depending on the dns server I use, the location my "digging" computer is located at and the time I'm resolving the dns name, I get different answers to the same question:

my pc using my local resolver:

```
dig googleapis.com +noall +answer

; <<>> DiG 9.10.6 <<>> googleapis.com +noall +answer
;; global options: +cmd
googleapis.com.     261 IN  A   216.58.207.132
```

my pc using google's dns server:

```
dig @8.8.8.8 googleapis.com +noall +answer

; <<>> DiG 9.10.6 <<>> @8.8.8.8 googleapis.com +noall +answer
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
googleapis.com.     106 IN  A   172.217.22.196
```

running "dig" from a container running in gke environment:

```
 # dig googleapis.com +noall +answer

; <<>> DiG 9.12.4-P2 <<>> googleapis.com +noall +answer
;; global options: +cmd
googleapis.com.     299 IN  A   172.217.16.196
```

same gke container, but about 10 mins later:

```
 # dig googleapis.com +noall +answer

; <<>> DiG 9.12.4-P2 <<>> googleapis.com +noall +answer
;; global options: +cmd
googleapis.com.     299 IN  A   172.217.18.164
```

Thats why I'm looking for some documentation, thats telling me the ip nets in question...
Google owns so much ip nets and only my 4 dig commands already answered with ip's out of 4 different networks...